# Is it necessary to make pthread_mutex_t variable volatile?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

In java we normally make the lock variable final static so that only one copy of it exists (Though I remember reading that even static variables can be duplicated into call stacks of two methods!)

But I am dealing with C and synchronization of data. I have declared a pthread_mutex_t variable on which N number of threads are going to lock to access a common resource.

What I a am not sure is if this variable is duplication proof or not (The problem with static variables in java which may or may not be duplicated into call stack of two methods). Because if they are duplicated by the compiler, then I fret locking maynot work. So do we need more radical access modifiers like "volatile" to make it truly singular?

Comment: The type could be declared ‘volitile’ in your platform. See declarations.

Comment: Yeah but is it necessary? Just trying to understand how compiler works around this aspect.

Comment: I am not proficient in multiprocessing. What I understand is that if a variable of ‘lock’ type can be changed from an interrupt, and it can be changed, you need to tell the compiler about it. So the compiler could remove some of it optimizations found in other, simpler cases.

Comment: No; you don't need to declare mutex variables as volatile.

Comment: As a proof of above thought I made up a hypothetical example. What if lock gets cached? So it might had been released but other code access the lock in cached state? Imagine that some interrupt did some changes and your code didn’t know about it. So the lock variable has too be volitile. In addition to other compiler tricks. But again, I am not at all savvy in this field.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Not at all! I was specifically referring to static primitive variables being duplicated  and not instantiation of N objects.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко: This does not apply because you never access the value of the `pthread_mutex_t` object. You only pass its address to the `pthread_mutex_...` functions, which are in turn responsible for the issues you're concerned about.

Comment: "...variables being duplicated" What does it mean for a variable to be duplicated? and under what circumstance does it happen? In my model of how Java works, every variable has a unique _location_ that never changes, and the value of a variable will never change unless my code _assigns_ it or, my code calls some library routine that assigns it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow In java If a static variable is accessed by two threads A() and B(), then updates by one, say A(),  is not necessarily visible instantaneously in the other B(). To prevent this race condition, you need to synchronize() access to the variable. This particular manifestation of static variable is what I referred to as duplicity.

Comment: Continuing with the rationale in the above comment, if possibility of such "race" conditions happening on mutex objects exists, then synchronization may break down in that split second transient time-frame during race.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only is it not necessary; it's **not permitted**. The argument to `pthread_mutex_...` functions has type `pthread_mutex_t *` and requires a valid pointer to a `pthread_mutex_t` object. A pointer to `volatile pthread_mutex_t` does not automatically convert just like a pointer to `const pthread_mutex_t` doesn't, because it's not usable where an unqualified one is needed. You could convert it via a cast, but then you just have undefined behavior for violating the contract of the functions.

Comment: >A pointer to `volatile pthread_mutex_t` does not automatically convert just like a pointer to `const pthread_mutex_t` doesn't, because it's not usable where an unqualified one is needed. Would you rephrase or explain this a little bit more please? Thanks

Comment: @susenj: It's permitted to access an unqualified object via pointer-to-const or pointer-to-volatile. The other way around is not permitted. This is completely obvious with const, which is why I mentioned const. For volatile, the reason is that when the compiler is generating code to access the object through a pointer to the unqualified type, it would not make any special considerations necessary for access to a volatile object. For example it may combine loads or stores, reorder them, remove redundant ones, etc.

Comment: As an important special case, you cannot use `memcpy` on volatile objects because its arguments are `void *`, not `volatile void *`.

Comment: @R.. Thanks for the answer, in that case  I was wondering what is the exact mechanism by which race conditions are avoided on mutex objects? Like if one or more number of bits in the mutex data structure changes, say, to indicate that object is now locked, how does compiler ensure its atomicity?

Comment: @Ace: That's of course an implementation detail, but the underlying method is generally that `pthread_mutex_t` is a struct type, and the individual members of the struct that need it have atomic type, or are exclusively accessed via asm fragments. Note that this is much better than the whole struct having atomic or volatile type, since there will be some members that are immutable for the object lifetime (e.g. type) and others that are only accessed under synchronization from the lock itself (e.g. recursive lock count).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.
If the variable you declare is global, then there will be only one (independently of the *volatile* qualifier). The volatile is usually used for variables that might change in the context of an interrupt (microcontrollers) or another thread, but not the lock itself.

It looks like the meaning of *volatile* is different in C and Java. Take a look at: https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword

> C's volatile keyword is a qualifier that is applied to a variable when
>   it is declared. It tells the compiler that the value of the variable
>   may change at any time--without any action being taken by the code the
>   compiler finds nearby.

Answer (score 0):

To put more emphasis on why this is needed you can see the following example:

If you write something like this :

```
void parallel_function(){
   //Example function, this doesn't exist, but it is good to let you understand
   pthread_mutex_is_free(&lock);

   doStuff();
}
```

Then the pthread_mutex_is_free will do some check to see if the mutex is free before lock it.
And here there is the catch, the problem lies in the compiler optimization because for him the code is executed from a single thread, so, it can choose to skip this check (the mutex is free) because he sees that that variable is set before as free, and never changed, so it will be always free and this is useless so skipped in the compiled code.
So using Volatile, force the compiler to avoid this sort of check, basically telling it to expect this variable to change magically and so to avoid static optimizations.